# How to print the output that is relevant to the pin code?

Tags: c, fgets

In this code, I am trying to print the data that is relevant to the pin code. It means if a user enters the pin code, the data of that pin code should be printed. Even if I print the data outside of the loop, read pin code from another file, it gives me the another file `2000` I tried a lot but failed.

**Data in the file**

```
Name,ID,Pin,Amount,Phone
Bilal Khan,1111111111111,1122,1000,1122334
Ali Ahmed,2222222222222,2233,2000,66778899
```

**Given output**

```
1000
2000
```

**Expected output**

```
2000
Relevant to the Pin Code.
```

**Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define STRING_LEN 200

int main(){  
  FILE *fp1 = fopen("file.csv", "r"); 
  char string[STRING_LEN];
  char * line = NULL, *pinFound = NULL, *wordOne = NULL, *wordTwo = NULL, *wordThree = NULL, *wordFour = NULL, *wordFive = NULL;  

  while(fgets(string, STRING_LEN, fp1)){
    line = strtok(string, "\n");
    pinFound = strstr(line, "2233");
    wordOne = strtok(line, ",");
    wordTwo = strtok(NULL, ",");
    wordThree = strtok(NULL, ",");
    wordFour = strtok(NULL, ",");
    wordFive = strtok(NULL, ",");
    if(pinFound)
      printf("%s\n", wordFour);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this output because strstr find 2233 in the two lines. `Bilal Khan,1111111111111,1122,1000,1122334` contains 2233. For this example you can replace `pinFound = strstr(line, "2233");` by `pinFound = strstr(line, ",2233,");` for test purpose, but the correct solution would be to use something like regexp.